# ZipException received while installing MongoDB from cloudify

Tags: mongodb, installation, cloudify

I was trying the 10-minute quickstart on cloudify and stumbled upon an error. I first installed the jdk, added `JAVA_HOME` to environment variables, then started the .bat file for the cloudify shell. (side note: I am a Windows 7 user).

I then tried install-application for petclinic-simple. I got an error after that during the install (which I forgot but I think it was an install error for mongoDB). Next, I decided to teardown-localcloud -force then closed the cloudify shell. After that, I tried the install-application for the petclinic again and I got a different error which gets repeated till timeout:

```
[127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
....
[127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
: : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
: Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
...Application installation timed out. Configure the timeout using the -timeout flag.
Operation failed.
```

I am still quite new to programming in general so please excuse me if I don't understand many of the complex things. I also tried restarting, deleting the folder, and re-extracting a new folder.

**Edit:**
Here's the output with --verbose but timeout 5

```
    cloudify@default> teardown-localcloud -force
    Teardown will shut down the local cloud. Do you want to continue  [y/n]?
    Failed to fetch the currently deployed applications list. Continuing teardown-localcloud.
    ..
    SHUTTING DOWN CLOUDIFY AGENT
    SHUTTING DOWN CLOUDIFY MANAGEMENT COMPONENTS
    SUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED LOCAL-CLOUD TEARDOWN
    cloudify@default> bootstrap-localcloud
    STARTING CLOUDIFY MANAGEMENT
    ..
    STARTING CLOUDIFY WEBUI
    ..
    STARTING CLOUDIFY REST
    CLOUDIFY LOCAL-CLOUD STARTED

    LOCAL-CLOUD INFO :
                    CLOUDIFY MANAGEMENT     http://127.0.0.1:8099/
                    CLOUDIFY GATEWAY        http://127.0.0.1:8100/
    Local-cloud started successfully. Use the teardown-localcloud command to shutdown all processes.
    cloudify@default> install-application --verbose -timeout 5 C:/Users/Calvin/Desktop/cloudify/recipes/apps/petclinic-simple
    Validating file petclinic-simple
    Uploading application petclinic
    Application [petclinic] with 2 services
    Service [mongod] 1 planned instances
    Service [tomcat] depends on [mongod] 1 planned instances
    .
    Deploying mongod with 1 planned instances.
    Deploying tomcat with 1 planned instances.
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    .....
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] tomcat-1 INSTALL invoked
    ....
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    .
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    .
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    .
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    .....
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    .
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    .
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    .....
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    .
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    ....
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    .
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
            at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
    ...
    [127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL failed. Reason: Event lifecycle external process exited with abnormal status code: 1 Caught
    : : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    : Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip
    java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Expand.expandFile(Expand.java:192)
            at org.apache.tools.ant

.taskdefs.Expand.execute(Expand.java:132)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at mongod_install.run(mongod_install.groovy:42) [ERROR]
...
[127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1] mongod-1 INSTALL invoked
.Operation failed. java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Application installation timed out. Configure the timeout using the -tim
eout flag.
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.ConditionLatch.waitFor(ConditionLatch.java:146)
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.rest.RestLifecycleEventsLatch.waitForLifecycleEvents(RestLifecycleEventsLatch.java:79)
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.rest.RestAdminFacade.waitForLifecycleEvents(RestAdminFacade.java:275)
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.commands.InstallApplication.doExecute(InstallApplication.java:113)
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.commands.AbstractGSCommand.execute(AbstractGSCommand.java:83)
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.commands.AdminAwareCommand.execute(AdminAwareCommand.java:36)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:221)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.Main.run(Main.java:191)
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.Main.run(Main.java:89)
        at org.cloudifysource.shell.GigaShellMain.main(GigaShellMain.java:122)

Operation failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message: "Error while expanding C:\Users\Calvin.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive" is the key.

This indicates that the mongoDB download may have failed the first time it was executed. See if you can open then file C:\Users\Calvin.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip

If you can't, delete the contents of "C:\Users\Calvin.cloudify\" and try installing again.

Comment: Since I couldn't open it, I deleted it but now I timeout when I try to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Please delete C:\Users\Calvin\.cloudify\mongod1\mongodb-win32-i386-2.0.2.zip

and then run the following ( Please use a long timeout, not 5 minutes.  ) :

- teardown-localcloud -force
- bootstrap-localcloud
- install-application --verbose -timeout 60
  FULL_PATH_TO_THE_PETCLINIC-SIMPLE

P.S. : 
In order to install MongoDB on Windows 7, you must run MongoDB with administrative credentials.

Does your user have such credentials? - If not, please use a user that has administrative credentials or add such credentials to your user.

and if it fails again, please send us all the log files.

Comment: I tried running the cloudify.bat as administrator since I install from there. Should I be installing it a different way?

Comment: I tried running it with timeout 25 but it was too long for me to paste. The 5 minute seemed to fit since it was just a repeat of the same. Would making it 1 hour help?

Comment: The timeout is not the problem. Did you delete the files under the .cloudify dir? If so, please delete all files in the cloudify /logs dir and run again. When the installation times out, zip the contents of the /logs dir and send them.

Comment: How do I send a file on here? And thank you guys for the responses.

Comment: Uploaded on dropbox: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x9za4acwxctot8c/s9jD3osrAY)